# How to form a reular expression to remove tabs and newlines in objective c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, regex, nsstring, nsregularexpression

i have a string containing tabs and newlines "**\r\n\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\tTHIS IS THE STRING \r\n\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t**". I have to remove multiple blank lines if it has .If it has ony one blank line ,i have to omit it.

So i tried using

```
 NSString *finalString = [orginal  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"^(.*)(\r\n\t){2,100}+"
                                                             withString:@""
                                                                options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                                  range:NSMakeRange(0,orginal.length)];
```

to remove newlines .Managed to remove few blank lines ,but its not working for all.Also i need to remove tab space.As i new to regex expression, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your question and clarify? Are you saying you have leading whitespace, you want to leave that? You're only worried about the trailing whitespace, but want to leave at least one `\r\n`? Or you want to trim all whitespace except if the string consists of solely a `\r\n`? It's not clearly precisely what you want to do. Perhaps provide us examples of a bunch of strings and what you'd like it trimmed to, so we can understand better. Or perhaps even better, explain the business problem you're trying to solve and we can tackle that.

Comment: Also, what specifically do you want to do with those tab character in there? Trim them? Leave them?

Answer (score 1):

Easier method would be the following:

```
finalString = [finalString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```